# Get the last 3 values of a TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

I have a Date/String TreeMap and I want to loop through the N last entries.

```
TreeMap<Date,String> map = new TreeMap<Date,String>();
map.put(new Date(2011,1,1), "32,1");
map.put(new Date(2011,3,1), "35");
map.put(new Date(2011,4,5), "38,9");
map.put(new Date(2011,8,2), "57!!");
```

Then I'm lost. I've found this :

```
NavigableSet<Date> dates = donnees.descendingKeySet();
```

Then I don't know how to say something like :

```
for(key in dates and i ; i from 0 to N)
{ do something }
```

Any help ?

Comment: You need to go through the map in the reverse order in a loop for the last 3 keys.

Comment: As a reminder, the JDK date/calendar class(es) uses wierd offsets for years and months (months start at 0, not 1, and the year for the date class is offset by 1900).  If that is what you really intended, that's fine.  However, keep in mind that there are predefined constants (`Calendar.JANUARY`) for the months (there's no easy help for the years, I'm afraid).  Also, that particular constructor is deprecated (but should still work).  This sort of behaviour is why some appreciate the JodaTime library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i=0;
for(Iterator<Date> it = dates.iterator(); it.hasNext() && i<3;) {
  Date date = it.next();
  doSomething();
  i++
}
```

Or (equivalent):

```
int i=0;
Iterator<Date> it = dates.iterator();
while(i<3 && it.hasNext()) {
  Date date = it.next();
  doSomething();
  i++
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to iterate though the [`descendingMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap%28%29):

```
private static final int N = 3;
...
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry entry : map.descendingMap().entrySet()) {
    if (i++ < N) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Fri Sep 02 11:39:05 EDT 2011=57!!
Thu May 05 11:39:05 EDT 2011=38,9
Fri Apr 01 11:39:05 EDT 2011=35
```

Addendum: Here's an example using `Calendar` in the default locale:

```
private static Date createDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
...
map.put(createDate(2011, 5, 3), "3-Jun-2011");
```

Comment: As an aside, you're using a deprecated `Date` constructor; use `Calendar.getInstance()` instead.

Comment: I tried to use Calendar instead of Date ... seems like I'm tired. How do you instanciate the 3rd of June ? I tried c Calendar.getInstance(); c.set(2011,6,3) .. but no way

Comment: I've elaborated above; note months start at zero. Alos, `Map.Entry` gives access to both key and value.

Comment: Yes, 0-based months in `java.util.Date` are one of the strongest reasons to switch to [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about the state of the tree? If not, then you could do [pollLastEntry()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#pollLastEntry%28%29). This will remove the last entry off the tree and give it to you. Do 3 times and you're done. Or you could flatten the tree into an arrayList and just return the last 3 elements.

Comment: if he cares, he could copy the map and then do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to loop through the items for the first three:

```
    int i=0;
    for(Date date: dates){

        //Do something

        if(i++ > 2){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- TreeMap implements NavigableMap.
- NavigableMap.descendingMap().
- descending Map.entrySet().iterator() // the first 3 entries which are of course
  the "last 3" because it is back to front.

You could just implement Comparator and pass it to the TreeMap so the "oldest" dates are at the head of the TreeMap.

Answer (score -1):

TreeMap to Array and read the array with a for loop with the condition i < 3

Comment: Terrible suggestion, there are better ways.